anaconda: failed to fetch kickstart file from http server
I am trying to create a RHEL8 template using HashiCorp Packer and Gitlab CI. During the build, I am encountering the following error:
"Failed to connect to 172.17.0.2 port 8899: connection timed out.
Warning: anaconda: failed to fetch kickstart from http://172.17.0.2:8899/ks.cfg"
I have verified connectivity from the Docker side using the following commands, and they all work fine:
ping 172.17.0.2
nc -zv 172.17.0.2 8621
curl -v http://172.17.0.2:8621/ks.cfg
The HTTP server is accessible on port 8621, and the ks.cfg file is retrievable without issues. I have also opened the necessary ports and confirmed that the DNS configuration is correct.
Despite these checks, the build process still fails with the aforementioned error.
Does anyone have suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?.
